# I am not getting FCM Registration token. I am trying to post android id and token on my api with the help of volley dependency

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a webview application and it working fine.
But I am not getting FCM Registration token. I am trying to post android id and token on my api with the help of volley dependency.

Please check below code

**Gradle.Build (App Level)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.app.redsix11"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0'
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
dependencies {
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:29.0.0')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:20.0.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.github.delight-im:Android-AdvancedWebView:v3.2.1'
}
```

**Gradle.build (Project Level)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:dist="http://schemas.android.com/apk/distribution"
    package="com.app.redsix11">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MEDIA_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_COMPANION_RUN_IN_BACKGROUND" />

    <application
        android:fullBackupContent="true"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".SecondActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity> <!-- Firebase Messaging Service -->
        <service
            android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java (For Webview Loading)**

```
package com.app.redsix11;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;vhhghgh
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.JsResult;
import android.webkit.WebChromeClient;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.app.AlertDialog;

import im.delight.android.webview.AdvancedWebView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdvancedWebView.Listener {
    String baseURL = "http://webtest1.webmoogle.com/hybrid/app";
    String webURL = baseURL;
    private AdvancedWebView WebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        String android_id = Settings.Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        webURL += "#index";
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        
        WebView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        WebView.setListener(this, this);
        WebView.setMixedContentAllowed(false);
        WebSettings webSettings = WebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.getAllowFileAccess();
        WebView.setGeolocationEnabled(true);
        WebView.addHttpHeader("X-Requested-With", android_id);
        WebView.addHttpHeader("X-API-VER", "1.7");

        WebView.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        WebView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        WebView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        WebView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);

        webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

        WebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

            @Override
            public boolean onJsAlert(WebView view, String url, String message, final JsResult result) {
                AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()).
                        setTitle("Attention").
                        setMessage(message).
                        setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                //do nothing
                            }
                        }).create();
                dialog.show();
                result.confirm();
                return true;
            } });
        WebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public void onReceivedError(WebView webView, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                try {
                    webView.stopLoading();
                } catch (Exception ignored){
                }

                if (webView.canGoBack()) {
                    webView.goBack();
                }
                webView.loadUrl("about:blank");
                AlertDialog alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
                alertDialog.setTitle("Error");
                alertDialog.setMessage("Check your internet connection and try again.");
                alertDialog.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                        startActivity(getIntent());
                    }
                });

                alertDialog.show();
                super.onReceivedError(webView, errorCode, description, failingUrl);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                /*if (!url.startsWith(baseURL) && !url.contains("cashfree.com")){
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(i);
                    return true;
                }else*/
                if (url.startsWith("tel:")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(url));
                    startActivity(intent);
                    view.reload();
                    return true;
                }
                view.loadUrl(url);
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                findViewById(R.id.imageLoading1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                findViewById(R.id.webView).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        });
        WebView.loadUrl(webURL);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction()== KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN){

            switch (keyCode){

                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                    if (WebView.canGoBack()){

                        WebView.goBack();
                    }
                    else {

                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        WebView.onResume();
    }

    /*@SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        WebView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }*/

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        WebView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
        WebView.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!WebView.onBackPressed()) { return; }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(String url, Bitmap favicon) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(String url) { }

    @Override
    public void onPageError(int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) { }

    @Override
    public void onDownloadRequested(String url, String suggestedFilename, String mimeType, long contentLength, String contentDisposition, String userAgent) { }

    @Override
    public void onExternalPageRequest(String url) { }
}
```

**MyFirebaseMessagingService.java**

```
package com.app.redsix11;
import android.util.Log;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    public void onNewToken(String token){
        Log.d(TAG,"The Token refreshed: "+token);
        sendToServer(token);
    }

    private void sendToServer(String token) {
        String postURL = "http://webtest1.webmoogle.com/hybrid/app?token"+token;
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, postURL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code to generate FCM key

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
        .addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
            if (!task.isSuccessful())
            {
                SOUT("Fetching FCM registration token failed");
                return;
            }
            SOUT("FCM:>"+task.getResult());
            sharedPref.edit().putString(Constants.shk_FCM_KEY,""+task.getResult()).commit();
        });
```